# Keep program going in background?

Tags: vb.net

I want my program to keep sending messages to a window (AppActivate(os)) even if that program is not in the foreground. Let's my program is open and I set it to App1 to send messages over and over, and I want to browse facebook. How can I make it so my program still runs in the background and sends messages while I browse facebook?

os = combobox1.text

The combobox retrieves each window handle.

Answer (score 0):

Use a thread of your function. It will not end until killed in task manager.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Test
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        Thread newThread = 
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(Work.DoWork));
        newThread.Start();
    }
}

class Work 
{
    Work() {}

    public static void DoWork() 
    {
        for(;;)
        {//FACEBOOK SPAMMER}
    }

}
```

More at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx3ezzs2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't look like anything in my code!

Comment: @GSto Hard to tell, as you didn't provide any code. Apart from being C# and not VB.NET...

Comment: I just noticed he tagged Basic... look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx3ezzs2(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2, I can't edit my answer because I am "spam"

Comment: Thank you. I have problems incorporating random code into my programs, can you give me an idea of what I have to edit?

Comment: I don't know what is in your file, but email me and I will surely help you!
 HateStackOverflow@tacticianstudios.com

Comment: There, I sent an email